# Eclipse Mars: How to Stop Updating Error Reporting Database

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars

I was using **Eclise Mars** version IDE.. Every Time I Start Eclipse,then

"**Updating Error Reporting Database**"

will come and hanging Eclipse.Please give me a solution for this problem..

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=464058

Answer (score 18):

This problem occurs generally while working behind a proxy.
You can disable it from the following :

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Error Reporting

there select the Never Send option

[image: Eclipse Mars Error Reporting Window]

In addition to this in Mars go to :
 Window -> Preferences -> General -> Startup and Shutdown

there uncheck the Eclipse Automated Error Reporting checkbox

[image: Eclipse Mars Startup and Shutdown options window]

Comment: This answer was more helpful to me as the path proposed is more complete.

Answer (score 14):

Go into PReferences-> Startup and Shutdown -> Uncheck Eclipse Automated Error Reporting